# How to import a value from a google sheet / pastebin and store it as a variable in an lua file?

Tags: lua, download

so I would like to get a value saved in a goole sheet cell or a value saved in pastebin.com
and store the value as an local variable in an .lua file

an small example would be great.

The thing is, I need to use a variable in an lua script for a game modification which only I will be able to change ( on the google sheet or pastebin site) , so that the defnied value of the vairbale automatically changed in the lua script as well.

Please let me know if its possible ..thanks!

Comment: Please set a tag corresponding to your game.  The game Lua API should provide a function to download URL.

Comment: Its not directly related to the game, Im asking if there is any way to get value from a google sheet to be stored as an variable, I just mentione dthat its for a game, my question has nothing to do with the game itself

Comment: Pure Lua is unable to download.  But every game adds to Lua its own incompatible function for downloading.  If you are using standalone Lua interpreter, try `os.popen("wget ....")`